# Unwanted margin android

Tags: android

I'm using an image carousel and for more reason there's a margin between the carousel and the title bar or action bar https://i.stack.imgur.com/k051p.jpg , and therefore I have to add a negative value to the top margin which is not desired...

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.mock.vivofusion.MainActivity"

    android:background="#f58b4c">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id ="@+id/viewPagerLayout">

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewPager"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
    .......

</RelativeLayout>
```

swipe_layout.xml(used for the carousel)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id = "@+id/image_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I can also provide the java classes if needed (the code is 'copy pasted' from a website).

LE: How can I make the scroll to be accessible only on the carousel area? Everywhere I swipe the images keep moving.

Comment: Having a negative margin isn't necessarily a bad thing. No performance overhead. It actually fairly common to do so because a lot of SDK widgets have internal padding that you'd like to override. But looking at your code, what the case more than likely is, the image that you set on the ImageView has some transparent background that is causing that dead space. To test this, go into the developer settings on your test device and enable layout bounds to see the actual rectangles that your views are being drawn inside of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be helpful, `android:scaleType="fitStart"`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id = "@+id/image_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitStart" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: @gigiman because I think the imageview is not having a margin rather it is adding padding to me. It happed with me once.